# Cannot append uniformly using Google Sheet Api V4 with empty values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to figure what combination of options for the ([Google Sheet Append Api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)) I need to uniformly append a row of data. My data could include empty values or not.

**Problem**:
I cannot seem to figure out a way to guarantee my row to append to a sheet starting from A1 every single time.

Here are the different behaviours I have seen:

**1)** `{ values: [["", "", 3]] }`
If I append this row 3 times, the rows will cover the ranges A1:C1, C2:E2, E3: G3. What I really want is A1:C3.

**2)** `{ values: [["3", "", 3]] }`
If I append this row 3 times, the rows will do something similar to 1) where it will cover the ranges A1:C1, C2:E2, E3: G3. Again, I want A1:C3.

**3)** `{ values: [["3", false, 3]] }`
If I append this row 3 times, everything works the way I want it to. It covers the ranges A1:C3.

What options do I specify in my append api request to guarantee that my rows will always start at A1 (even if the first *n* columns are empty)?

Comment: This is [automatic table detection biting you](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#appending_values). I would expect **2** and **3** to behave the same, however. Can you share the path you are using for the request? I would think that specifying the desired range would work, though you may need to update the requested row (e.g. 1st request is for `"A1"`, next for "A2", etc).